# xamarin RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager StackFromEnd missing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i cant find any method to set the RecyclerView to setStackFromEnd(true). neither on the recyclerview nor on the LinearLayoutManager

```
mLayoutManager = new Android.Support.V7.Widget.LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the `StackFromEnd` property in the `LinearLayoutManager`. You can associate the `LinearLayoutManager` with the `RecyclerView` like so:

```
var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity)
{
    StackFromEnd = true
};
recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: thank u very much, after half of a day searching and testing, this piece of code solved my problem.